# Need two Excel Macros to be one

Tags: vba, excel

I have two blocks of code in excel VBA, running two separate macros, producing two separate files. I want one macro that runs the first piece of code, then have the second section take over the file, do its thing, then produce a file.

The first macro combines many TXT files into one.

The second macro changes the column structure to fit a database.

The end goal is to have a combined, formatted .xlsx file saved somewhere.

Here is my the first piece of code:

```
    Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" _
        (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
        ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, _
        ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" _
        (ByVal hProcess As Long, _
        lpExitCode As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" _
        (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
        ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, _
        ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" _
        (ByVal hProcess As Long, _
        lpExitCode As Long) As Long
#End If


Public Const PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = &H400
Public Const STILL_ACTIVE = &H103


Public Sub ShellAndWait(ByVal PathName As String, Optional WindowState)
    Dim hProg As Long
    Dim hProcess As Long, ExitCode As Long
    'fill in the missing parameter and execute the program
    If IsMissing(WindowState) Then WindowState = 1
    hProg = Shell(PathName, WindowState)
    'hProg is a "process ID under Win32. To get the process handle:
    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, False, hProg)
    Do
        'populate Exitcode variable
        GetExitCodeProcess hProcess, ExitCode
        DoEvents
    Loop While ExitCode = STILL_ACTIVE
End Sub


Sub Merge_TXT_Files()
    Dim BatFileName As String
    Dim TXTFileName As String
    Dim XLSFileName As String
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim DefPath As String
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim oFolder
    Dim foldername

    'Create two temporary file names
    BatFileName = Environ("Temp") & _
            "\CollectCSVData" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy-h-mm-ss") & ".bat"
    TXTFileName = Environ("Temp") & _
            "\AllCSV" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy-h-mm-ss") & ".txt"

    'Folder where you want to save the Excel file
    DefPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
    If Right(DefPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        DefPath = DefPath & "\"
    End If

    'Set the extension and file format
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 97-2003
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007 or higher
        FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
        'If you want to save as xls(97-2003 format) in 2007 use
        'FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
    End If

    'Name of the Excel file with a date/time stamp
    XLSFileName = DefPath & "MasterCSV " & _
                  Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yyyy h-mm-ss") & FileExtStr

    'Browse to the folder with CSV files
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set oFolder = oApp.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select folder with .TXT files", 512)
    If Not oFolder Is Nothing Then
        foldername = oFolder.Self.Path
        If Right(foldername, 1) <> "\" Then
            foldername = foldername & "\"
        End If

        'Create the bat file
        Open BatFileName For Output As #1
        Print #1, "Copy " & Chr(34) & foldername & "*.txt" _
                & Chr(34) & " " & TXTFileName
        Close #1

        'Run the Bat file to collect all data from the CSV files into a TXT file
        ShellAndWait BatFileName, 0
        If Dir(TXTFileName) = "" Then
            MsgBox "There are no csv files in this folder"
            Kill BatFileName
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Open the TXT file in Excel
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=TXTFileName, Origin:=xlWindows, StartRow _
                :=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
                ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, _
                Space:=False, Other:=False

        'Save text file as a Excel file
        Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Wb.SaveAs Filename:=XLSFileName, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Wb.Close savechanges:=False
        MsgBox "You find the Excel file here: " & vbNewLine & XLSFileName

        'Delete the bat and text file you temporary used
        Kill BatFileName
        Kill TXTFileName

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is the second code:

```
Sub Edge_Filer_Convertor()
 ' MoveColumns Macro

Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long

'Constant values
 data_sheet1 = "Sheet1"
 target_sheet = "Reorganized_Edge_EDD" 'Specify the sheet to store the results
 iRow = Sheets(data_sheet1).UsedRange.Rows.Count 'Determine how many rows are in use

'Create a new sheet to store the results
 Worksheets.Add.Name = "Reorganized_Edge_EDD"

'Start organizing columns
 For iCol = 1 To Sheets(data_sheet1).UsedRange.Columns.Count

'Sets the TargetCol to zero in order to prevent overwriting existing targetcolumns
 targetCol = 0


'Read the header of the original sheet to determine the column order

If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Sample Type" Then targetCol = 5
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Sample Matrix" Then targetCol = 8
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Sample Identification" Then targetCol = 14
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Sample Date" Then targetCol = 15
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Sample Time" Then targetCol = 16
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Report Number / Sample Group Identifier" Then targetCol = 18
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Primary Laboratory Identification" Then targetCol = 19
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Secondary Laboratory Identification" Then targetCol = 20
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Date Laboratory Received" Then targetCol = 21
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Time Laboratory Received" Then targetCol = 22
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Laboratory Report Date" Then targetCol = 23
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "CAS Identification Number" Then targetCol = 24
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Analysis" Then targetCol = 25
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Result" Then targetCol = 26
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "LOQ" Then targetCol = 27
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "LOD" Then targetCol = 28
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "DL" Then targetCol = 29
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Qualifier" Then targetCol = 30
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Units" Then targetCol = 31
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Date Analyzed" Then targetCol = 32
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Analyst" Then targetCol = 33
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Batch Identification" Then targetCol = 34
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Extraction Method" Then targetCol = 35
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Preparation Method" Then targetCol = 36
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Preparation Date" Then targetCol = 37
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Preparer Initials" Then targetCol = 38
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Spike Value" Then targetCol = 39
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Spike Reference Value" Then targetCol = 40
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Low Limit" Then targetCol = 42
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "High Limit" Then targetCol = 43
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Run Number" Then targetCol = 46
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Sequence Number" Then targetCol = 47
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Duplicate Result" Then targetCol = 48
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Dilution Factor" Then targetCol = 49
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "MSD Result" Then targetCol = 50
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "QC Qualifier" Then targetCol = 51
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "Comments" Then targetCol = 52


'If a TargetColumn was determined (based upon the header information) then copy the column to the right spot
 If targetCol <> 0 Then
 'Select the column and copy it
 Sheets(data_sheet1).Range(Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol), Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(iRow, iCol)).Copy Destination:=Sheets(target_sheet).Cells(1, targetCol)


'Add Correct Headers

    Range("A1") = "Request_Number"
    Range("B1") = "Request_Date"
    Range("C1") = "Authorized_By"
    Range("D1") = "Sample_Field_Type_Composite_or_Grab"
    Range("E1") = "Sample_Laboratory_Type"
    Range("F1") = "WAD_Number"
    Range("G1") = "Profile_Number"
    Range("H1") = "Sample_Matrix"
    Range("I1") = "Sample_Description"
    Range("J1") = "Site_of_Generation"
    Range("K1") = "Source_Process_Generation"
    Range("L1") = "Program"
    Range("M1") = "Laboratory_ID_Number"
    Range("N1") = "Sample_Identification"
    Range("O1") = "Sample_Date"
    Range("P1") = "Sample_Time"
    Range("Q1") = "Sampled_By"
    Range("R1") = "Report_Number_or_Work_Order_Number"
    Range("S1") = "Primary_Laboratory_Identification"
    Range("T1") = "Secondary_Laboratory_Identification"
    Range("U1") = "Date_Laboratory_Received"
    Range("V1") = "Time_Laboratory_Received"
    Range("W1") = "Laboratory_Report_Date"
    Range("X1") = "CAS_Identification_Number"
    Range("Y1") = "Analysis"
    Range("Z1") = "Result"
    Range("AA1") = "LOQ"
    Range("AB1") = "LOD"
    Range("AC1") = "DL"
    Range("AD1") = "Qualifier"
    Range("AE1") = "Units"
    Range("AF1") = "Date_Analyzed"
    Range("AG1") = "Analyst"
    Range("AH1") = "Batch_Identification"
    Range("AI1") = "Extraction_Method"
    Range("AJ1") = "Preparation_Method"
    Range("AK1") = "Preparation_Date"
    Range("AL1") = "Preparer_Initials"
    Range("AM1") = "Spike_Value"
    Range("AN1") = "Spike_Reference_Value"
    Range("AO1") = "Percent_Recovered"
    Range("AP1") = "Low_Limit"
    Range("AQ1") = "High_Limit"
    Range("AR1") = "RPD_Reference_Value"
    Range("AS1") = "RPD_Limit"
    Range("AT1") = "Run_Number"
    Range("AU1") = "Sequence_Number"
    Range("AV1") = "Duplicate_Result"
    Range("AW1") = "Dilution_Factor"
    Range("AX1") = "MSD_Result"
    Range("AY1") = "QC_Qualifier"
    Range("AZ1") = "Comments"


'Change data type to match database
Columns("A:AZ").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"

Range("B:B,O:O,U:U,W:W,AF:AF,AK:AK").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

Range("P:P,V:V").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "h:mm;@"



End If

Next iCol 'Move to the next column until all columns are read


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to do, is create a third macro with this:

```
Sub Run_Macros()

    Call Merge_TXT_Files()
    Call Edge_Filer_Convertor()

End Sub
```

**Search before post.**

Answer (score 0):

Combining wouldnt be too difficult as you can literally just add the instructions form macro#2 to the bottom of the first one. You may need to go through it and make sure there are no conflicting variables declarations but it should be easy peasy.